# Performance issue:-Compression not working in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, angularjs, nginx, compression

I had created an app in Rails and using angularjs.The app in now live.The issue I am having is that the site is taking a long time to load(upto 30 secs).The application.js file is around `1Mb` and the css file is around `700kb`(after using rake assets:precompile).Hence the site does not load till the js file is loaded in the browser.So I was trying to gzip files in Nginx.
The below is my code I have used in Nginx config file:-

```
http {

gzip  on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)”;


server {
         listen   80;
          server_name example.com;
      rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;    
}

  server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
    root /home/webuser/apps/production/public;
location ^~ /assets/ {
    allow all;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_static  on;
    expires      365d;
    add_header   Last-Modified "";
    add_header   Cache-Control public;
  }
```

So I want to know What I am doing wrong.Also is it of any use to gzip the files which are already minified.

It would of great help if I get solution to this.The most important thing currently is to increase the performance of the website.

Comment: How do you know that gzip is not working? Try `curl -v -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -o /dev/null http://www.example.com/assets/style.css 2>&1 | grep -i Content-Encoding`

Comment: @AlexeyTen It is not giving me any response.What ooes it mean

Comment: Have you restarted nginx? Have you put some real file in my command instead of `style.css`?

Comment: I have restarted nginx and also put *.js instead of style.css ..What other kind of files can I check in it